# MongoDB query issue - error after second query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, caching, database

Right, I have this really weird problem, that is probably more related to how MongoDB works rather than a coding issue.

I'm making a website in Javascript (mostly) that is very heavy on jquery, using a MongoDB database and a nodejs server. I have users which have walls, and lots of information updates asynchronically. Because of this, I have to make dives into the database quite often, mainly to update things - for example if a user leaves a message on somebody's wall, or adding a friend.

The problem is, that once I make a query - trying to make another one just like it afterwards fail. They are literally identical (I tested this, copy&paste, they were a bit different first). It doesn't matter if I use find or update, the result is always null from the second query. I am closing the database after each dive, and returning as well just for good measure.

I can't find any issues anywhere where multiple queries to the same place fails after one succeeds. It's as if there is a lock somewhere, because I'm 100% sure my query is correct, and shouldn't return null. Not even hard coding works. The first query works perfectly. Same data, same collection.

So, my question is: does MongoDB have some query cache that could be blocking the query, or is there something else I've missed in how the queries work? Do you have any good tips and hints when having to do multiple database queries?

I get TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined as a result of the query returning null.

I hope this is enough information for anyone to have a clue what's wrong. I'm not providing any code as I think this is more a matter of me not really getting how MongoDB works rather than a coding issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is now solved. I have no idea what caused it, but I rewrote some large chunks and that did the trick. Thanks for your time!